# py.test: how to pass a test-method parmetrization data to the test object?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module with tests and I want to add some fixture parametrization in a `conftest` file. I don't want to mention this fixture in the test module, but I want this fixture to be available in the test_-method's `self` argument. How to do it?
In other words, how to make this code work?

#### conftest.py

```
def pytest_generate_tests (metafunc):
    my_class = metafunc.function.__class__
    metafunc.fixturenames.append('foo')
    metafunc.parametrize('foo', [1, 2])
```

#### test.py

```
class TestFoo (object):
    def test_foo (self):
        assert self.foo > 0
```

Comment: Why would you want this? Can't you simply use explicit parametrize?

Comment: I have few people, who write tests. I want to be able to change some behavior without making them to change their test files.